# css added from remote node.js but not apply on html page

Tags: javascript, node.js

The application on which m working I am calling CSS file from remote server dynamically and **remote server side we are using node.js where file loads but not apply CSS on the page**.

When I try to add the path other than node.js server path it works properly and when I add some CSS from javascript this also works.

I tried following option

1. loadCSS = function(href) {
   var href =   "http://192.168.0.64:3001/public/stylesheets/enduserchat.css";
   var cssLink = $("");
   $("head").append(cssLink); 
   }; // not working
2. $('head').append('http://192.168.0.64:3001/public/stylesheets/enduserchat.css" type="text/css" />') // (remote side node.js) not working
3. **$('head').append('http://demo23.easternenterprise.com/webrtc/css/chats.css" type="text/css" />') // working (without node js)**
4. function loadjscssfile(filename) {
   var fileref=document.createElement("link");
   fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
   fileref.setAttribute("href", "http://192.168.0.64:3001/public/stylesheets/enduserchat.css")
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
   } // not working

Plz help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are loading the css after creation of the webpage. But changes will work AFTER refreshing of the webpage.
The solution: at server side combine all styles, javascript and html, and after that return it to the client side.

Have a nice day!